# ¿Como buscar los elementos que fueron modificados dentro de un array de arrays en JS?

Tags: javascript, array

Hola a todos antes que nada buen día y gracias por sus respuestas y opiniones, tengo el siguiente problema quiero encontrar en un array que contiene otros arrays el elemento que se ha modificado para ello he realizado lo siguiente guardo los elementos que recibo en dos variables diferentes en una de ellas hago las modificaciones y con el otro array la idea es compararlo para saber que elemento ha sido modificado y obtenerlo tengo la siguiente estructura. Guardo los datos que me llegan del servidor en Data y modifiableData.
Guardo los datos que me llegan del servidor en Data y modifiableData

```
data = [
      [1, 'Darinel', 'Cigarroa'],
      [2, 'Isis', 'Oriana'],
      [3, 'Manuel', 'Arcos']
    ];

modifiableData = [
      [1, 'Darinel', 'Cigarroa'],
      [2, 'Isis', 'Oriana'],
      [3, 'Manuel', 'Arcos']
    ];
```

Supongamos que en modifiableData  he cambiado el primer nombre a Daro quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
  modifiableData = [
          [1, 'Daro', 'Cigarroa'],
          [2, 'Isis', 'Oriana'],
          [3, 'Manuel', 'Arcos']
        ];
```

Quiero encontrar ese array modificado y traer solo ese array tener este resultado:

```
[1, 'Daro', 'Cigarroa'],
```

Cabe mencionar que estoy recibiendo el dato que estoy modificando siguiendo nuestro ejemplo 'Daro' por lo que supongo que debe de haber más de una solución estaba solucionando buscando por su id el cual sería el primer valor de los arrays pero este también puede ser modificado y falla mi solución ahora estoy intentando de la siguiente manera pero sin éxito.

```js
  data = [
          [1, 'Darinel', 'Cigarroa'],
          [2, 'Isis', 'Oriana'],
          [3, 'Manuel', 'Arcos']
        ];

modifiableData = [
          [1, 'Daro', 'Cigarroa'],
          [2, 'Isis', 'Oriana'],
          [3, 'Manuel', 'Arcos']
        ];

const result = modifiableData.filter((element) => element === 'Daro' );
console.log(result);
```

De ante mano les agradezco cualquier opinión, enlace alguna documentación o respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que estas tratando de filtrar datos - que son arreglos - dentro de otro arreglo. Por lo que el `filter` que estas realizando, esta iterando sobre el padre de los `arrays`.

Cambialo por esto, y te funcionará

```
const result = modifiableData.filter(element => {
  const item = element.find(i => i === 'Daro');
  return item;
});
```

Lo que estamos haciendo, es que dentro del padre, por cada iteración, pregunte a cada hijo o arreglo mediante **[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**, si existe tal coincidencia.

Si tienes dudas nos comentas.

Comment: Muchas gracias debuggeare el código para tenerlo más claro, si me surgen dudas regreso para preguntar.

Comment: Urbano Riverra Okay si me surgieron dudas siempre que trabjao con arrays donde hay un elemento padre conteniendo todo me confundo mucho y suelo complicarme mi duda es la siguiente debuggeando me di cuenta que el filter en cada iteración devuelve los arrays por separado hasta alli todo bien y en el metodo find cada iteración equivale a cada elemeto del array y tengo entendido que find devuelve el valor del primer elemento del array que cumple la función de prueba proporcionada entonces mi pregunta es ¿Como es que tenemos todo el array en item?, muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el método `find`, trae el primer elemento dentro del arreglo que coincide con la condición que le entregas; por lo tanto, independiente si los elementos de tu arreglo, son objetos o arrays, _find_ mostrará dicho elemento coincidente.  Espero se entienda la explicación :)